# How can I edit the way links show in wordpress, not the permalinks?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wordpress

Hey guys, I'm trying to use my wordpress categories as subdomains without using a plugin because the only working plugin doesn't seem to work with the new wordpress.

So I created the subdomains and I'm searching for a way to let this category1.mysite.com to show the content of www.mysite.com/category/category1 without redirecting.

but my question is how to edit the links manually for www.mysite.com/category/category1
when someone goes to my site the theme shows links this way www.mysite.com/category/category1
instead of showing the subdomain, so what files or database table should I edit to change the way my theme shows the links of categories and subcategories ?

and also if you have a way to to the first step in the .htaccess file please tell me about it.
and thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Look into get_categories() function - this will return an array so you can do the following

```
foreach(get_categories() as $category) {
    $url = $category->category_nicename.'.mydomain.com';
}
```

from this you should be able to build your own UL with the information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will need to use [Apache's Mod_Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) feature in a way that is not standard with WordPress permalink features.